# MVC Controller calling UoW (unit of work) directly instead of going through Service Layer

Tags: design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design, asp.net-mvc, repository

Currently im injecting my Unit of Work inside the controller.

I figured out that in most of the designs, controllers calls the service layer and service calls the repository/DAL layer.

Most of the times in the controller, I don't have/need any logic and just need to fetch from db and pass it to view.

I do this by calling the repository from the unit of work, is this a bad practice?

I basically have only a two layered architecture instead of a 3 tiers. Im kinda missing the service layer/application layer

```
Views(MVC) <- Controllers(MVC) -> UoW(DB) -> Repository(DB) -> EF(DB) -> SQL Server(DB)
```

For the interested i can send my git repo in private.

Comment: Questions containing the words "bad practice" are unanswerable unless you can articulate your specific concerns.  Clearly it already works.

Comment: You don't have to implement abstractions you don't need, regardless of what the "good practices" say.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't really have any logic beside fetching data from the repository and showing it, then it is perfectly fine to skip a separate service/application layer. In fact it would be a bad practice to have an extra layer in that case, since you would be complicating the architecture for no benefit.

You can always introduce a new layer at a later point if the need arises.

Comment: _"You can always introduce a new layer at a later point"_ I agree with the YAGNI-centric answer, but I do want to add a footnote here that for sufficiently large codebases, inserting another layer can become a considerable task. If there's a reasonable expectation that this may be necessary in the future, it can be better to pre-emptively already set the layer up (even if it's just a passthrough at the moment). Nonetheless, +1 from me as overengineering can be as much of a problem as underengineering.

Comment: @Flater it will be the same amount of work to introduce it whether you do it prematurely or when it is actually needed.

Comment: I adamantly disagree. Do note that I said "for sufficiently large codebases". The larger a codebase is, the more troublesome a rewiring becomes (compared to building it right the first way).

Comment: @Flater Agree, it is obviously more work to introduce on a larger codebase that on a smaller. But having a superfluous extra layer will make it more work to grow a smaller codebase to a larger, so you just distribute the  work over more time.

Comment: I can agree with that for small codebases. The combined conclusion is then that the larger a codebase is/will be, the more you should favor pre-emptive layering. For small codebases, it can be put off until necessary. For large codebases, it's generally more beneficial to pre-empt (at least earlier than you would for a small codebase).